# How Elasticsearch determines which node in cluster to query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have two ES nodes (in a cluster) in different locations and I would like to determine my application to use the nearest one to avoid network latency.

I have set up [Forced Shard Allocation Awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html) to make every of these nodes "independent" (containing Primary shard or Replica of another Primary but never both of them) like

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.my_attr.values: my_attr_val1, my_attr_val2
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: my_attr
```

Now I know I can force my query to be run on specific node by adding to the query [Preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) like:

```
_only_nodes:my_attr:my_attr_val1
```

but as far as I understand it would fail in case of node failure - so basically I don't want to do this.

What I can do is to set

```
_prefer_nodes:my_attr:my_attr_val1
```

or to just do nothing and let ES do it's job. The question is - **is ES choosing "the best" (let say the nearest) node to query or it just takes random one**? How Elasticsearch determines the node to ask?

The version of my ES is 5.5.0

Comment: you could read this blog to have more insight on the subject https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-response-latency-in-elasticsearch-with-adaptive-replica-selection

Comment: thank you for the link it is very interesting - however it seems that ARS was implemented in ES 6.1 when my instance is 5.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior in 5.5, if you don't set the preference, is to route the request to allocated shards in a round-robin fashion. ES doesn't have "nearest node" system.